# In Postgres, how can I query for all objects before a certain date to the millisecond resolution?

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, backend, querying

I'm writing a Go program that needs to query for all instances of an object before a certain timestamp? I've tried several approaches.

Approach 1: Query for objects using a Golang time.Time object:

```
func CountObjectsBeforePeriod(id string, period time.Time, db dbwrap.DB) (int32, error) {
    countQuery := "COUNT(rate_id)"
    reader := postgres.NewBitemporalReader(db)
    var count int32
    periodString := period.String()
    periodTimestamp := "to_timestamp('" + periodString + "', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')"
    err := reader.SelectCurrent(countQuery).
        From(dataSource).
        Where(sq.Eq{idCol: id}).
        Where(periodCol + " < " + periodTimestamp).
        QueryRow().
        Scan(&count)
```

Result: This doesn't fail! But, I need to query for all objects at the **millisecond** resolution. Thus, this query does not return the expected result.

Approach 2: Change to_timestamp to add milliseconds to the function.

```
periodTimestamp := "to_timestamp('" + periodString + "', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MS')"
```

Result: This fails with the error: `pq: date/time field value out of range: "2021-01-16 00:06:32.076143 +0000 UTC""`

Approach 3: Query using the unix timestamp:

```
func CountObjectsBeforePeriod(id string, period time.Time, db dbwrap.DB) (int32, error) {
    countQuery := "COUNT(rate_id)"
    reader := postgres.NewBitemporalReader(db)
    var count int32
    periodString := strconv.Itoa(period.Unix())
    periodTimestamp := "to_timestamp('" + periodString + "')"
    err := reader.SelectCurrent(countQuery).
        From(dataSource).
        Where(sq.Eq{idCol: id}).
        Where(periodCol + " < " + periodTimestamp).
        QueryRow().
        Scan(&count)
```

Result: Same as approach 1. It doesn't crash but it doesn't query at the millisecond resolution.

Approach 4: Query using the unix nano timestamp:

```
periodString := strconv.Itoa(period.UnixNano() / 1000000000)
```

Result: Integer overflow for the period; some of the periods we are using are quite large and cannot be converted into UnixNano.

Any other suggestions? Thank you for the help.

Comment: `select '2021-01-16 00:06:32.076143 +0000 UTC'::timestamptz; ERROR:  invalid input syntax ...`. `select '2021-01-16 00:06:32.076143+00000 '::timestamptz;` or `select '2021-01-16 00:06:32.076143  UTC'::timestamptz;` work. So decide on either a time zone offset or a time zone abbreviation. Also not sure about the purpose of `'"` in `'" + periodString + "'`.

Comment: The purpose of '" + periodString + "' is because if it's not surrounded by quotation marks, the query fails. Not sure if it's a problem with the library we're using, but the quotes are needed.

Comment: Is there a simple way to remove the time zone offset in Go?

Comment: I don't use Go so I cannot provide a concrete answer. I can point you at [Format](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.Format).

Comment: You appear to be using something other than the Go standard library (squirrel?). In general its best to pass go variables into the query as parameters rather than converting the values to strings yourself (the driver will handle the conversion for you) e.g. (untested and assumes squirrel which I rarely use) `.Where(sq.Lt{periodCol: period})`.